# How to order database results by distance?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, geolocation, distance

I want to order the results from a database according to the distance to an object.
Both my object and my database items have `lat` and `lng` and I can calculate distance with **haversine**.

The problem is that they need to be selected by distance from the database. I can't pull out the whole database, make calculations and then take the results I need, because ... *a kitty would die every time I do it*.

- Some people suggest putting haversine formula to the `order_by`. How
  many kittens will die?
- Some people suggest some kind of **spatial plugins**. What do they do? Which one should I use?
- Another alternative that seemed ugly was that you take manually some distance and make a square by ruling out everything bigger and smaller of the `lat` and `lng`. If you don't have enough results, or you have too many results, you correct the distance and run query again.

Can anyone tell what is the best way that I should go with pro's con's. Also I am using LAMP/MAMP with CakePHP.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your table ? with some sample data maybe ?

Comment: Tip: Check out [geocoding-with-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/)

Answer (score 0):

Use both:

```
WHERE table.latitude BETWEEN $latmin AND $latmax
   AND table.longitude BETWEEN $lonmin AND $lonmax
ORDER BY haversine(....)
HAVING haversine(...) < $your_desired_distance
```

It'll still be a heavy duty order-by, but you'll have eliminated any "obvious" out-of-range candidates with the very simple/light-weight `WHERE` filters, so you'll be doing the actual distance calculations on a small(er?) subset of all possible records.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a quadkey. It's a spatial index using a space filling curve. It's not an exact solution but very fast and you are free to use the haversine formulae. You can download my php class hilbert -curve @ phpclasses.org. It also uses a mercator projection.